# C++: Get Template of an existing object

Tags: c++, templates

Sorry for the headline. I have no idea for a better headline.
I have this code:

```
template <class T>
class Object
{
    public:
    T a1;
};

Object<short> myObj;

int main() {
    myObj.a1 = 10000;
    // ......
}
```

(I know, this is not perfect code. It is a sample code to show my problem.)

Now I need to create a new variable in main() function. The variable must
have the same type like the template parameter of myObj (short in sample code).
Is there a way to do this?

```
int main() {
    myObj.a1 = 10000;

    myObj.TEMPLATE_PARAM_WHATEVER myNewVar = 99; // myNewVar must have the type short
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If `Object` is under your control, you can add a member typedef:

```
// In `class Object`:
using type = T;
// in `main()`:
decltype(myObj)::type myNewVar = 99;
```

Here's another option that doesn't require modifying `class Object`:

```
decltype(myObj.a1) myNewVar = 99;
```

If `Object` doesn't actually have a member variable with the right type, you can still extract the template argument:

```
template <typename T> struct ObjectType {};
template <typename T> struct ObjectType<Object<T>> {using type = T;};
template <typename T> using ObjectType_t = typename ObjectType<T>::type;
// In `main()`:
ObjectType_t<decltype(myObj)> myNewVar = 99;
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to do this?

Yes it is possible using a `typedef` or an *alias declaration*. One crude example is shown below:

```
template <class T>
class Object
{
    public:
    using parameterType = T;
    T a1;
};

Object<short> myObj;

int main() {
    myObj.a1 = 10000;
    decltype(myObj)::parameterType newVar = 99;
       
}
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mEHyBrsdq9AbzWcP).

Note that in this particular example you can also just write:

```
decltype(myObj.a1) newVar = 99;
```

Comment: Or for that matter, `decltype(myObj.a1) newVar = 99;`.

Comment: @alfC Yes, in this particular example that will work. I have added your suggestion as a note at the end of my answer.

Comment: Thanks alfC and Anoop. Thats is what i'm looking for